# adding calendar event in performFetchWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, ios8

I am trying to add calendar event in

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

based on some data app received for creating a calendar event.

**My problem is :** the code for creating calendar event runs without any issue but, the **event** does not shows up on calendar. when i bring the app back to foreground after my "add event" code has executed, I can then see the calendar event added when I press the home button

Also if my code runs 2-3 times when the app is in background, it seems like the event entry stays in "pending" state after code execution and when the app comes into foreground all events are added immediately.

All I have to do is just bring the app in foreground once and then press home button again - now I can see all pending calendar entries which should have been added once the code has executed some time earlier.

Is this known behaviour? could anyone suggest working workaround which does not lead to appstore rejection?

CODE:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
             NSLog(@"EKEventStore error = %@", error);

         if (granted)
         {
             NSLog(@"EKEvent *event ");

             EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
             event.title = @"test";
             event.startDate = [NSDate date];
             event.endDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:600];
             [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

             NSError *err = nil;
             [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

             if (err)
             {
                 NSLog(@"not added");
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"successfully added");
             }
         }
     }];

    NSLog(@"background fetch");
}
```

Comment: what code you are using ?

Comment: did you call get permission for add data to calendar

Comment: yes. the app have the permissions. adding code as well.

Comment: you want make alaram ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create event in main thread.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandle {
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"EKEventStore error = %@", error);
    }
    if (granted) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"EKEvent *event ");

            EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
            event.title = @"test";
            event.startDate = [NSDate date];
            event.endDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:600];

            [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
            NSError *err = nil;
            [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

            if (err) {
                NSLog(@"not added");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"successfully added");
            }
        });
    }
}];
NSLog(@"background fetch");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are missing some steps to execute code in background.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
// Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
// If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
}];

}
```

You also have to return result so OS decide time interval to call the same method again on basis of your return result as below

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"EKEventStore error = %@", error);
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
    }
    if (granted) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"EKEvent *event ");

            EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
            event.title = @"test";
            event.startDate = [NSDate date];
            event.endDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:600];

            [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
            NSError *err = nil;
            [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

            if (err) {
                NSLog(@"not added");
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"successfully added");
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
            }
        });
    }
}];
NSLog(@"background fetch");
}
```